# Send mail using google mailing service and google openId authentication

Tags: c#, email, gmail, google-oauth, google-openid

I am working on application which allows user to sign in using google and then send mail using google credentials. I have used google api to authenticate user into an application, but the problem is that I don't know how to send mail using already logged in user's credentials and google mail service. How can I send mail???

Answer (score 0):

How many applications do you use where you login with Google and the app/site is able to send mail as you? This is not a common pattern and will probably surprise most users. I would like to understand the use case better.

If there is a very good reason to do this (where the app is making it easier for user to send emails and user is aware of it), the only way you can do this is to request full access to their gmail/IMAP and then use that token to send email as the user. The problem with this approach is that the user needs to give access to full gmail account to the developer/app and that is something that should not do unless they fully trust that application.

Comment: There is only one application where I login and send mail. Can I use [gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) to login as well as to send mail?

Comment: Yes. In addition to the scopes you need for doing login, just add gmail related scopes and use the token.

Comment: Thanks @nvnagr . Can you please provide code sample for sending mail using gmail API? I searched the gmail documentation, but unable to find any code for.Net.